# Alignment problem when using enumerate with the answers package

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate, theorems

When using `enumerate` inside the `answers` package to generate a list of exercises the first item is not correctly indented compared to all other items which come after it. Is it possible to use `enumerate` within the `answers` package and obtain correct alignment for all items?

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\renewcommand{\Solutionlabel}[1]{\small{#1.}}
\newtheorem{ex}{}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{ex}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Part 1. of the first exercise which is not correctly aligned
  compared to all other subsequence items in the list.  
\item Part 2. of the first exercise.
\item Part 3. of the first exercise.
\end{enumerate}
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
The next exercise.
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This has nothing to do with `answers`

Comment: @omegadot -- Just add a `~` after the first `\begin{ex}` like this: `\begin{ex}~ \begin{enumerate} ... \end{enumerate}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you specify some (explanatory) text after `\begin{ex}` or add the `~` character after `\begin{ex}`.

The 'problem' is due to the definition of `ex` and `\newtheorem` and not related to the `answers` package at all.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\renewcommand{\Solutionlabel}[1]{\small{#1.}}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[section]

\begin{document}

\chapter{First} 
\section{First}
\begin{ex}~
\begin{enumerate}
\item Part 1. of the first exercise which is not correctly aligned
  compared to all other subsequence items in the list.  
\item Part 2. of the first exercise.
\item Part 3. of the first exercise.
\end{enumerate}
\end{ex}
\begin{ex} Or with some text
\begin{enumerate} 
\item Part 1. of the first exercise which is not correctly aligned
  compared to all other subsequence items in the list.  
\item Part 2. of the first exercise.
\item Part 3. of the first exercise.
\end{enumerate}
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

[image]